Error on CircleCI when execution a QA automation project
I am currently working on a QA automation project, specifically on implementing a solution to delete testing environments once the execution is finished. I have a Python script named setup.py that performs this task effectively in my local environment. The script correctly schedules the deletion of the testing environment.
To provide more detail, the script creates the testing environment and then triggers the delete_organization function, which automatically schedules the deletion of the testing environment for later the same night. This script is executed automatically on CircleCI.
This file also writes the data in the .env file, this file looks like this everything it is executed
ORGANIZATION=Pedro
SCHOOL_YEAR=2024
APP_BASE_URL=https://qaa-kristen-richards-1719497724.dev.company.com
API_BASE_URL=https://api.dev.company.com
USER_PASSWORD=Xno2R0c5X3BPNEpw
API_USER_PASSWORD=Qm1hM0tPIXBpKSYr

setup.py file
"""
Setup

This script helps to create a new organization and generates a .env file with
the base URLs of Enroll and Sync Service products.
"""
import time
from enroll.common import create_env_file_content
from enroll.organization import default_organization_data, CreateOrganizationService
from enroll.common.utils.password import decode_password
from enroll.common.api.base_api import BaseApi
import os
import datetime
import requests


from argparse import ArgumentParser


def create_organization(payload, env):
    return CreateOrganizationService(env).perform(payload)


def four_digit_argument(value):
    ivalue = int(value)
    if ivalue < 1000 or ivalue > 9999:
        raise Exception("%s is not a valid 4-digit integer")
    return ivalue

if __name__ == '__main__':

    organization_data_payload = default_organization_data()
    parser = ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        '-e',
        '--env',
        default='dev',
        type=str,
        required=False,
        help='Environment to setup the Golden Master to trigger the Suite against it',
        choices=('sandbox', 'dev', 'staging', 'test', 'performance', 'local', 'demand'),
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '-o',
        '--org',
        default='',
        type=str,
        required=False,
        help='Organization to setup the Golden Master to trigger the Suite against it',
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '-y',
        '--year',
        default=0,
        type=four_digit_argument,
        required=False,
        help='Organization to setup the Golden Master to trigger the Suite against it',
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '-p',
        '--password',
        default=organization_data_payload['automation_password'],
        required=False,
        help='Automation user password for the created organization'
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '-ap',
        '--apipassword',
        default=organization_data_payload['automationapi_password'],
        required=False,
        help='Automation Api user password for the created organization'
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    ## running the org on a pre existing org is determined only by the presence of both parameters, org and year. 
    ## when both are given it is assumed that the organization exists in the specified environment
    is_a_pre_existing_org = args.org != '' and args.year != 0
    ## by default use the organization data payload if is not a pre-existing-org 
    if not is_a_pre_existing_org:
        args.year = organization_data_payload['school_years'][0]
        ## only set the org name for not pre existing orgs if it was not given by parameter,
        ## there is a valid scenario of specifying the org name for the creation (by omiting the year)
        if args.org == '':
            args.org = organization_data_payload['subdomain']


    organization_data_payload['subdomain'] = args.org
    organization_data_payload['school_years'] = [args.year, args.year - 1]

    # when the organization already exists
    # then we skip the creation step, the password for the automation user
    # is pre-defined, later we could improve this part by allowing the script
    # to automatically create the automation@company.net and
    # automationapi@company.net users automatically when those doesn't exist already
    if is_a_pre_existing_org:
        args.password = decode_password('U1VoQ1ZVNVhaRllvY3pCQQ==')
        args.apipassword = decode_password('U1VoQ1ZVNVhaRllvY3pCQQ==')
    else:
        response = create_organization(organization_data_payload, args.env)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception(
                "An error occurred while creating a new organization", response)

    env_file_content = create_env_file_content(
        args.env, args.org, args.year, args.password, args.apipassword)

    env_file = open('.env', 'w')
    env_file.write(env_file_content)
    env_file.close()

    # Wait for the data to be created
    if args.env != 'local':
        time.sleep(50)

api_client = BaseApi()  # Create an instance of the BaseApi class
api_client.authenticate_account(credentials={'username': 'automation@company.net', 'password': decode_password(os.environ.get('USER_PASSWORD'))})

if BaseApi._current_username:
  username = BaseApi._current_username
  token = BaseApi._tokens.get(username)

def get_org_id(token):

  url = f"{os.environ.get('API_BASE_URL')}/secret/api/because/company/policies/{os.environ.get('ORGANIZATION')}"

  headers = {
      "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
      "organization": os.environ.get('ORGANIZATION'),
      "yr": os.environ.get('SCHOOL_YEAR'),
  }

  try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for non-2xx status codes
    data = response.json()  # Parse the JSON response

    # Extract the value of the "id" key
    if "id" in data["data"]:
        return data["data"]["id"]
    else:
        print(f'Key "id" not found in response data')
  except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

def delete_organization():

    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    formatted_date = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    url = "https://123456.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/schedule/qaa"

    headers = {
        "X-KEY": "slkjfdksh2378374"
    }

    data = {
      "org_id": get_org_id(token),
      "org_subdomain": os.environ.get('ORGANIZATION'),
      "org_namespace": os.environ.get('ORGANIZATION'),
      "date_to_remove": formatted_date,
      "platform_stage": "development",
      "user": "automation@company.net",
      "environment": "development"
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("The organization will be deleted tonight.")
    else:
        error_message = response.json().get('message', "Unknown error")
        print(f"Error deleting organization: {error_message}")

delete_organization()

The problem relies on the execution on CicleCI which is throwing this error
ENVIRONMENT: dev
ORGANIZATION: -
YEAR: -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 121, in <module>
    api_client.authenticate_account(credentials={'username': 'automation@company.net', 'password': decode_password(os.environ.get('USER_PASSWORD'))})
  File "/opt/automation/enroll/common/utils/password.py", line 14, in decode_password
    byte_password = bytes(password, encoding='UTF-8')
TypeError: encoding without a string argument

Exited with code exit status 1

The password.py file looks in this way
import base64


def decode_password(password: str) -> str:
    """
    Decode a base64-encoded password string.

    Args:
        password (str): The base64-encoded password string to be decoded.

    Returns:
        str: The decoded password string.
    """
    byte_password = bytes(password, encoding='UTF-8')
    return base64.b64decode(byte_password).decode('UTF-8')


def encode_password(password: str) -> str:
    """
    Encode a password string using base64 encoding.

    Args:
        password (str): The password string to be encoded.

    Returns:
        str: The base64-encoded password string.
    """
    byte_password = password.encode('ascii')
    return base64.b64encode(byte_password).decode('UTF-8')

the config_continuation.yml for the CircleCI execution looks in this way
version: 2.1

orbs:
  slack: circleci/slack@4.12.1

parameters:
  parallelism:
    type: integer
    default: 4

jobs:
  build:
    parallelism: << pipeline.parameters.parallelism >>
    working_directory: /opt/automation
    docker:
      - image: enggaccounts/pytest-base-ci:0.0.2
        auth:
          username: $DOCKERHUB_USER
          password: $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD
    environment:
      USER_PASSWORD: your_password_here # Add your password here

    steps:

      - run: 
          name: Figuring Enroll Data 
          # it will figure:
          # environment,
          # organization,
          # year,
          # all based on a branch naming convention
          # by default if the standard isn't followed it will assume the defaults 
          # (defaults implies creating a new org on the development environment and running the suite for current year)
          # the naming convention is as follows:
          # ENROLL_123_mycustom_automation_branch_ENV_demand_ORG_mycustom-org-123_YEAR_2023
          # what matters is what comes after _ENV_
          command: |
              if echo $CIRCLE_BRANCH | grep -q "_ENV_"; then
                params_str="${CIRCLE_BRANCH#*_ENV_}"
                env=${params_str/_*}
                org=''
                year=''
                is_custom='0'
                
                if echo $CIRCLE_BRANCH | grep -q "_ORG_"; then
                  params_str="${CIRCLE_BRANCH#*_ORG_}"
                  org="${params_str/_*}"
                fi

                if echo $CIRCLE_BRANCH | grep -q "_YEAR_"; then
                  params_str="${CIRCLE_BRANCH#*_YEAR_}"
                  year="${params_str/_*}"
                fi

                if echo $CIRCLE_BRANCH | grep -q "_CUSTOM"; then
                  is_custom='1'
                  echo "export IS_CUSTOM=${is_custom}" >> "$BASH_ENV"
                fi

                if [ ${#env} -gt 0 ]; then
                  echo "$env"
                  echo "export ENROLL_ENVIRONMENT=${env}" >> "$BASH_ENV"
                else
                  echo "Custom branch pattern detected but ENV was not defined!"
                fi

                if [ ${#org} -gt 0 ]; then
                  echo "$org"
                  echo "export ENROLL_ORGANIZATION=${org}" >> "$BASH_ENV"
                else
                  echo "Custom branch pattern detected but ORG was not defined!"
                fi

                if [ ${#year} -gt 0 ]; then
                  echo "$year"
                  echo "export ENROLL_YEAR=${year}" >> "$BASH_ENV"
                else
                  echo "Custom branch pattern detected but YEAR was not defined!"
                fi

              else
                echo "$env"
                echo 'export ENROLL_ENVIRONMENT="dev"' >> "$BASH_ENV"
              fi

      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v2-dependencies-{{ checksum "Pipfile.lock" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v2-dependencies-

      - run:
          name: Install pipenv
          command: sudo apt install -y pipenv

      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: pipenv install

      - run:
          # SETUP the suite to run as specified,
          name: Setup the organization
          command: |
            if [ ${#ENROLL_ENVIRONMENT} -gt 0 ] && [ ${#ENROLL_ORGANIZATION} -gt 0 ] && [ ${#ENROLL_YEAR} -gt 0 ]; then
              echo "ENVIRONMENT: ${ENROLL_ENVIRONMENT}"
              echo "ORGANIZATION: ${ENROLL_ORGANIZATION}"
              echo "YEAR: ${ENROLL_YEAR}"
              pipenv run python3 setup.py -e ${ENROLL_ENVIRONMENT} -o ${ENROLL_ORGANIZATION} -y ${ENROLL_YEAR}
            elif [ ${#ENROLL_ENVIRONMENT} -gt 0 ]; then
              echo "ENVIRONMENT: ${ENROLL_ENVIRONMENT}"
              echo "ORGANIZATION: -"
              echo "YEAR: -"
              pipenv run python3 setup.py -e ${ENROLL_ENVIRONMENT}
            else
              echo "ENVIRONMENT: -"
              echo "ORGANIZATION: -"
              echo "YEAR: -"
              pipenv run python3 setup.py
            fi


      - run:
          name: Organization information
          command: |
            ORGANIZATION=$(grep 'ORGANIZATION=' .env | cut -d '=' -f2-)
            SCHOOL_YEAR=$(grep 'SCHOOL_YEAR=' .env | cut -d '=' -f2-)
            APP_BASE_URL=$(grep 'APP_BASE_URL=' .env | cut -d '=' -f2-)
            echo "Organization: $ORGANIZATION"
            echo "School Year: $SCHOOL_YEAR"
            echo "App base url: $APP_BASE_URL" 

      - save_cache:
          key: v2-dependencies-{{ checksum "Pipfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - "~/.cache/pipenv"

      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: |
            set -e
            TEST_FILES=$(circleci tests glob "enroll/**/tests/*.py" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)
            mkdir -p reports

            if [[ "$IS_CUSTOM" == 1 ]]; then
                pipenv run pytest $TEST_FILES --html=reports/index.html --junitxml=reports/junit.xml -m custom

            else
                pipenv run pytest $TEST_FILES --html=reports/index.html --junitxml=reports/junit.xml
            fi

      - store_test_results:
          path: reports

      # Save artifacts
      - store_artifacts:
          path: reports

      # if you want to modify slack notification template
      # https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/attachments
      # we are using attachments in order to help us see each message within it's own section
      - slack/notify:
          event: pass
          custom: |
            {
              "attachments": [
                {
                  "color": "#1cbf43",
                  "fallback": "A $CIRCLE_JOB job has succeeded!",
                  "text": "<https://github.com/$CIRCLE_USERNAME|$CIRCLE_USERNAME> A `$CIRCLE_JOB` job has succeeded!",
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "title": "Project",
                      "value": "$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME",
                      "short": true
                    },
                    {
                      "title": "Branch",
                      "value": "$CIRCLE_BRANCH (<$CIRCLE_PULL_REQUEST|PR>)",
                      "short": true
                    }
                  ],
                  "actions": [
                    {
                      "type": "button",
                      "text": "Job $CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM",
                      "url": "$CIRCLE_BUILD_URL"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }

      - slack/notify:
          event: fail
          custom: | # including template here so it is easier to customize
            {
              "attachments": [
                {
                  "color": "#ed5c5c",
                  "fallback": "A $CIRCLE_JOB job has failed. $CIRCLE_PR_USERNAME",
                  "text": "<https://github.com/$CIRCLE_USERNAME|$CIRCLE_USERNAME> A `$CIRCLE_JOB` job has failed!",
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "title": "Project",
                      "value": "$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME",
                      "short": true
                    },
                    {
                      "title": "Branch",
                      "value": "$CIRCLE_BRANCH (<$CIRCLE_PULL_REQUEST|PR>)",
                      "short": true
                    }
                  ],
                  "actions": [
                    {
                      "type": "button",
                      "text": "Job $CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM",
                      "url": "$CIRCLE_BUILD_URL"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }

workflows:
  build-workflow:
    jobs:
      - build


and the config.yml looks in this way
version: 2.1

setup: true

orbs:
  continuation: circleci/continuation@0.2.0

jobs:
  determine-parallelism:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/base:edge
    resource_class: medium
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Determine parallelism
          command: |
            # Put command/logic here to determine parallelism
            echo "determining"
            if echo $CIRCLE_BRANCH | grep -q "_ENV_" &&
                echo $CIRCLE_BRANCH | grep -q "_ORG_" &&
                echo $CIRCLE_BRANCH | grep -q "_YEAR_"; then
              echo "lets use 1"
              PARALLELISM=1
            else
              echo "lets use 4"
              PARALLELISM=4
            fi
            echo "lets create file"
            
            echo "{\"parallelism\": $PARALLELISM}" > pipeline-parameters.json
      
      - continuation/continue:
          configuration_path: .circleci/config_continuation.yml
          parameters: pipeline-parameters.json

workflows:
  build-setup:
    jobs:
      - determine-parallelism

How can I fix this error to make it work on CircleCI as well? Please note that it is not possible to hardcode the password in the YAML files, as the password is different for each execution. Each execution on CircleCI creates four containers, each with a different testing environment, to enable parallel execution. I think I need to pass somehow as parameters this value store in decode_password(os.environ.get('USER_PASSWORD'))

idk but I have gotten errors from circleci to I think it may be the config.yml file Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv==2021.5.29 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pipenv==2021.5.29
also for your error you may want to check out this
https://medium.com/@rajputgajanan50/typeerror-string-argument-without-an-encoding-in-python-957c225978d9
for your "TypeError: encoding without a string argument" error
